# Listening pushes onto a public github repository

Tags: node.js, github

I'm trying to create a node server that updates a database based on information in a public github repository. I would like to know if it is possible to receive a notification of some kind, like subscribe to a webhook or create a trigger with an url to own service, or check a github service every day, any way to know when there has changes.
I could do scraping over the github page every day to read the master version but I want to know if exist some service to do this "the rigth way"

Comment: See [the official library](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/#readme).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way to be notified of this.  GitHub provides [WebHooks](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/webhooks?apiVersion=2022-11-28), which will send your server a request every time a certain event occurs.

Note that for efficiency reasons, GitHub only filters on the type of event, so if you, for example, ask to be notified of the `push` event and there are some pushes you don't care about, it's your responsibility to ignore the ones you don't want.

There is [a Node.js library that's part of Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/) that you can use, but you can also just register a regular HTTP server using the API or the web interface as well.